# Unable to build the project due to androidx.core library mismatch

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, androidx

I was trying to make some changes to my existing project this morning but I am unable to generate the build which was working till yesterday.

I am getting an error that says the following,

> The minCompileSdk (30) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata
> (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater
> than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
>
> Dependency: androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-alpha01.

I am still using the targetSDK as 29 and haven't configured it to be 30 yet and also, I am using Facebook SDK and Admob SDKs for various reasons. Anybody else facing this issue lately?

Comment: `targetSdkVersion` is completely separate from `compileSdkVersion`

Comment: Forgot to mention that, targetVersion and compileVersion are at 29

Comment: Did you update anything in Android Studio?

Comment: No, I did not.
Using 4.1 with Kotlin v1.4.21

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact error too.

The solution that worked was to change in build.gradle (app) this line

> implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"

to this:

> implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"

And no changes to `compileSdkVersion` or `targetSdkVersion` were necessary

### Or

change both `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 30

Comment: Still the same even after changing the core to 1.6.0. I think I will have to update the sdk to 30